# Pandas/Python - Create New Column which pulls out only digits from a column string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am re-creating a script that compares addresses from two separate databases and tries tries to find instances where they are the same. One dataframe is approximately 50,000 rows and 40 columns, the other is 170,000 rows and 122 columns. I mention this only because and of the fuzzy logic/levenshtein distance solutions I was reading about were taking way too long (waiting for 72 hours).

The address column is a string data type. I was hoping to possible come up with a way where I could create a new column called 'just_numbers' and pull out all characters that are digits from the string; however, I haven't been able to quite put it together yet.

I know the following is incorrect, but I was thinking something along the lines of this logic:

```
def get_digits(text):
    return ''.join(c for c in text if c.isdigit())
```

```
df['just_numbers'] = get_digits(str(df['Primary_Address__Full']))
```

I guess the trick is that I first have to iterate through each character in the cell and then if that character is a digit, pull it out and put it into the new column.

I tried looking through other solutions, but I wasn't quite able to come up with anything, I'm sure this question seems simplistic, I apologize, I'm new to this...

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely on the right track to solving the problem.

A Pandas data frame has a method called 'apply': https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

```
from faker import Faker # Third party package for creating fake data
import pandas as pd

fake = Faker()

address = fake.address
columns = ["Primary_Address__Full"]
df = pd.DataFrame([address() for _ in range(10)], columns=columns)

print(df)

def get_digits(string):
    return ''.join(c for c in string if c.isdigit())

df['just_numbers'] = df.Primary_Address__Full.apply(get_digits)
print(df)
```

OUTPUT:

```
"""    Primary_Address__Full
0  2348 Emma Mills Suite 717\nPort Josephfort, MA...
1  15764 Dwayne Ways Apt. 573\nEast Courtneystad,...
2   3450 Goodwin Vista\nWest Danielborough, DE 74865
3  19302 Kevin Squares\nSouth Courtneytown, KS 63487
4          75521 Rhonda Highway\nRossburgh, TN 23977
5        271 Barrett Gateway\nPort Michael, NV 04799
6  943 Hernandez Rapid Suite 325\nBelindaland, ME...
7      10235 Alexander Terrace\nJohnnyland, AL 28056
8  38561 Welch Highway Apt. 699\nMillsview, PA 14456
9  8778 Hicks Parkways Apt. 615\nNorth Deancheste...
                               Primary_Address__Full   just_numbers
0  2348 Emma Mills Suite 717\nPort Josephfort, MA...   234871756627
1  15764 Dwayne Ways Apt. 573\nEast Courtneystad,...  1576457359934
2   3450 Goodwin Vista\nWest Danielborough, DE 74865      345074865
3  19302 Kevin Squares\nSouth Courtneytown, KS 63487     1930263487
4          75521 Rhonda Highway\nRossburgh, TN 23977     7552123977
5        271 Barrett Gateway\nPort Michael, NV 04799       27104799
6  943 Hernandez Rapid Suite 325\nBelindaland, ME...    94332569643
7      10235 Alexander Terrace\nJohnnyland, AL 28056     1023528056
8  38561 Welch Highway Apt. 699\nMillsview, PA 14456  3856169914456
9  8778 Hicks Parkways Apt. 615\nNorth Deancheste...   877861546874"""
```

If you only want the first group of digits, you can use the `extract` method: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html

The `extract` method uses regular expressions.

```
df['just_numbers'] = df.Primary_Address__Full.str.extract(r'(\d+)')
print(df)
```

OUTPUT:

```
"""    Primary_Address__Full just_numbers
0  2348 Emma Mills Suite 717\nPort Josephfort, MA...         2348
1  15764 Dwayne Ways Apt. 573\nEast Courtneystad,...        15764
2   3450 Goodwin Vista\nWest Danielborough, DE 74865         3450
3  19302 Kevin Squares\nSouth Courtneytown, KS 63487        19302
4          75521 Rhonda Highway\nRossburgh, TN 23977        75521
5        271 Barrett Gateway\nPort Michael, NV 04799          271
6  943 Hernandez Rapid Suite 325\nBelindaland, ME...          943
7      10235 Alexander Terrace\nJohnnyland, AL 28056        10235
8  38561 Welch Highway Apt. 699\nMillsview, PA 14456        38561
9  8778 Hicks Parkways Apt. 615\nNorth Deancheste...         8778"""
```

Comment: I'm not sure where I'm going wrong still...when I run it with the fake data it works fine, but when I run it with my real data I get TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable. Since I will be performing an inner join between the two dfs, I was just_numbers as unique as possible, so the first solution is defintiely the one I want...thank you for the start

Comment: Do you have any sample data you can share? I will try to reproduce your error.

Comment: After some digging, I think I found that adding a lambda and using str(x) seemed to fix it: .apply(lambda x: get_digits(str(x)) Thank you again for sending the .apply method over...as you can see, still a beginner haha

Comment: I have only been using Pandas for a few months so I still consider myself a beginner. It makes sense that your adding `str(x)` would resolve the issue. The data types in the values in that column are not all type `str`—at least one of them is type `float`—so casting the values to a type `str` makes sense.